# Animation has yellow tint

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACdb4.png)My animation has a yellow tint to it after I made it an AVI JPEG file.[image]

What the video looks like.

[image]

What the frame actually looks like.

I made this animation by outputing the frames into a JPEG file, then I put the images into an image strip where I export it as an AVI JPEG. I viewed the final animation using the Movie and TV tool that Windows uses.

I am rendering using Cycles.

[image]

If you need any more details please contact me.

Nevermind, I fixed it. It was just the movie player that tinted it.

Comment: Hadn't you asked the same question before? Instead of asking again edit the original question with more information.

Comment: OK. What information do I still need?

Comment: Explain in detail what you did. How you are rendering? As an image sequence and then encoding later? What settings are you using? Are the images shown from blender or are you previewing in other software? What settings are you using for color management.  Also please read the following link: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101712/blender-vse-background-color-of-video-from-imported-image-sequence/101764#101764